# Robot Frame work - Image upload not working

Tags: robotframework

Im facing a strange issue in not able to upload an image through a drop down.  i.e. I selec "Image" as the option from the drop down and try to upload an image file.  This uploading is not working.

however, if I select "video" as the option and try to upload a video file, the upload is successful.

Can someone help me please.  Im mentioning the "image" and "video" locators.

**Image (upload fails)**

**# Select Image**
click element         css:body > app-root > div > app-master > div > div.full-height > div > div > div > app-campaign-builder > div > div > div > app-setup-media > div > div > app-modal-popup > div > app-base-modal > div > div > div.flowbuilder-overlay-content > app-setup-node-properties > app-richcard-carousel > form > div > div.block-level-left > section > app-tabs > div.tab-body > app-richcard-carousel-tab-selection > form > div > div > div > div.flex-row.image-containter > ng-conatiner > div.form-fields.align-center > div > div > app-dropdown > div > div > select > option:nth-child(1)

#upload the image file
Choose File /html/body/app-root/div/app-master/div/div[3]/div/div/div/app-campaign-builder/div/div/div/app-setup-media/div/div/app-modal-popup/div/app-base-modal/div/div/div[2]/app-setup-node-properties/app-richcard-carousel/form/div/div[1]/section/app-tabs/div[1]/app-richcard-carousel-tab-selection/form/div/div/div/div[1]/ng-conatiner/div[2]/section/app-file-uploader-crop-image/div/div/div/input         ${TestDataDir}/FileUpload.jpeg

**Video (upload works fine)**

**# Select Video**
click element        css:body > app-root > div > app-master > div > div.full-height > div > div > div > app-campaign-builder > div > div > div > app-setup-media > div > div > app-modal-popup > div > app-base-modal > div > div > div.flowbuilder-overlay-content > app-setup-node-properties > app-richcard-carousel > form > div > div.block-level-left > section > app-tabs > div.tab-body > app-richcard-carousel-tab-selection > form > div > div > div > div.flex-row.image-containter > ng-conatiner > div.form-fields.align-center > div > div > app-dropdown > div > div > select > option:nth-child(2)

#upload a video file
Choose File          /html/body/app-root/div/app-master/div/div[3]/div/div/div/app-campaign-builder/div/div/div/app-setup-media/div/div/app-modal-popup/div/app-base-modal/div/div/div[2]/app-setup-node-properties/app-richcard-carousel/form/div/div[1]/section/app-tabs/div[1]/app-richcard-carousel-tab-selection/form/div/div/div/div[1]/ng-conatiner/div[2]/section/app-file-uploader-video/div/div/input       ${TestDataDir}/Video Upload.mp4

Comment: do you face the same issue when performing the steps manually?

Comment: No..... it all works fine manually @JiriJanous

Comment: what is the error or o/p?

Comment: @SujitNeb

Element with locator <PATH MENTIONED> not found...

Comment: Since you have a space in your file name, I suggest adding a quotes around it and retry. It may think as a second arg